# NumericRangeQuery vs TermRangeQuery depending on IndexedEmbedded

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

Using hibernate search 5.3, I have a date that is on a nested field which is annotated with indexedembedded at a custom getter method and in that object, there's a date that I want indexed. When I use the indexedembedded field with @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO) and @DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY) creating the query creates a TermRangeQuery, but when I add anoher custom getter to the object that is indexed that returns the exact same date object and annotate that getter with datebridge and field the same as the nested one it creates a NumericRangeQuery. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Situation A:

```
@Indexed
Object A {
    List ObjectB

    @IndexedEmbedded
    getFirstObjectB()
}

Object B {
    Timestamp timestamp

    @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO)
    @DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY)    
    java.util.Date getDate(){
        return change timestamp to Date
    }
}
```

Situation B:

```
@Indexed
Object A {
    List ObjectB

    getFirstObjectB()


    @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO)
    @DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY)    
    java.util.Date getObjectBDate() {
         return getFirstObjectB().getDate();
    }
}

Object B {
    Timestamp timestamp

    java.util.Date getDate(){
        return change timestamp to Date
    }
}
```

In situation A, when creating the query on field "firstObjectB.date" (hibernate search's default naming) the query created is a TermRangeQuery. In the second, creating the query on "objectBDate" (also default naming) creates a NumericRangeQuery. They should be returning the exact same object retrieved through the exact same code path. The only difference I can tell is that one uses indexedembedded to index a nested field while the other directly indexes the field as part of the indexed object.

Comment: Could you share your code? Hard to understand your issue without it. You might find the template at https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates useful to share your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Added an example of the situation. Hope that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Hmmm, it definitely looks weird and it's worth an investigation on our part. Could you put together a test case using https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene ? It shouldn't take you too long. Once you have a test case, attach it to a JIRA issue here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa and we'll take a look at what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, and also sorry it's taken me a while to get back to you. I don't know how much time I'll have in the near future, but as soon as I get a chance, I definitely will set up a test case. Thanks for your help, and also just want to add that in all hibernate search is fantastic and easily one of the coolest things I've ever worked with so thanks for all the work you guys have put into it.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Just realized you also responded on my other question regarding the boolean issue. I finally have some time now to work on test cases. Would you prefer two completely distinct projects or do you want both test cases in the same project, either sharing an annotated entity or using distinct ones?

Comment: you can put them in the same projects but 2 different entities would be nice so that the tests are independent!

Comment: any chance you could find some time to provide a test case for this issue? It would be nice to be able to fix it before we release the next version if it's a real bug. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Unfortunately no. At this point the only reason I'm sure I didn't imagine it was that someone had created an issue for the date range not working. Hopefully I'll have some better luck in the near future.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet I got some time to look into this further. While I still haven't had any luck getting the test case to work, but I got some time to do some debugging. It seems like the issue has something to do with the allFieldDescriptors map in IndexedType DescriptorImpl and however that's set. When I search by the the indexed embedded field, the field isn't present in allFieldDescriptors, but when I search by the custom getter indexed field, that field is. The thing that's throwing me now is that when I search by the indexed embedded one, the custom getter isn't in the map either.